# How do I limit/filter entries in a sub document?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pipeline, subdocument

*Answer is at bottom of my question*

I am close to getting what I want... but just a little bit off.

what I want to return is all active kennels and if any kennel has a booking(s), for a specific Year (2024), an array of dayOfYear (eg [100,101,102,103]) and an array of rooms (eg [1,2] )

Here is a [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dDUElBePqxD)

This is what I am getting now

```
[
        {
            "_id": "65ef79a2331ab6aef4fae5d4",
            "identifier": "1.1.6x10",
            "active": true,
            "partition": "1",
            "length": 10,
            "width": 6,
            "bookings": [
                {
                    "_id": "65ef88f444e7d6607498ac2e",
                    "year": 2024,
                    "dayOfYear": 100,
                    "duration": 6
                },
                {
                    "_id": "65f0ca69f2667460e600a46a",
                    "year": 2024,
                    "dayOfYear": 107,
                    "duration": 1
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

this is what I would **like** to get - all kennels, *AND* the kennel with identifier "1.1.6x10" should show a single booking for 2024 - 100, (*for clarity - bookings for any Kennel with a booking on 2024 - 100 should also be returned, but for this example data, only the 1.1.6x10 kennel has a booking*)

```
[
        {
            "_id": "65ef79a2331ab6aef4fae5d4",
            "identifier": "1.1.6x10",
            "active": true,
            "partition": "1",
            "length": 10,
            "width": 6,
            "bookings": [
                {
                    "_id": "65ef88f444e7d6607498ac2e",
                    "year": 2024,
                    "dayOfYear": 100,
                    "duration": 6
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "65ef79a2331ab6aef4fae5d5",
            "identifier": "1.2.6x10",
            "active": true,
            "partition": "2",
            "length": 10,
            "width": 6,
            "bookings": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "65ef79a3331ab6aef4fae5e5",
            "identifier": "2.1.4x10",
            "active": true,
            "partition": "1",
            "length": 10,
            "width": 4,
            "bookings": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "65ef79a3331ab6aef4fae5e6",
            "identifier": "2.2.4x10",
            "active": true,
            "partition": "2",
            "length": 10,
            "width": 4,
            "bookings": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "65ef79a3331ab6aef4fae5e7",
            "identifier": "2.3.4x10",
            "active": true,
            "partition": "3",
            "length": 10,
            "width": 4,
            "bookings": []
        }
    ]
```

Here is the mongodb pipeline I am using, aggregating on 'kennels'

```
  let pipeline = [
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'rooms',
        localField: 'REF_RoomID',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'room',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$room',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'bookings',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'REF_KennelID',
        as: 'bookings',
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        $and: [
          { active: true },
          { 'room.number': { $in: [1,2] } },
          //
          // this is my problem area
          //{ 'bookings.year': { $eq: 2024 } },
          //{ 'bookings.dayOfYear': { $eq: 100 } },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        REF_RoomID: 0,
        room: 0,
        'bookings.REF_KennelID': 0,
        'bookings.__v': 0,
      },
    },
  ];
```

Here is some data:

**Rooms**

```
{
  "_id":  "65ef799f331ab6aef4fae5ba",
  "number": "1",
  "length": "10",
  "width": "12"
},
{
  "_id": "65ef79a0331ab6aef4fae5be",
  "number": "2",
  "length": "10",
  "width": "12"
}
```

**Kennels**

```
{
  "_id": "65ef79a2331ab6aef4fae5d4",
  "REF_RoomID":  "65ef799f331ab6aef4fae5ba",
  "identifier": "1.1.6x10",
  "active": true,
  "partition": "1",
  "length": 10,
  "width": 6
},
{
  "_id": "65ef79a2331ab6aef4fae5d5",
  "REF_RoomID": "65ef799f331ab6aef4fae5ba",
  "identifier": "1.2.6x10",
  "active": true,
  "partition": "2",
  "length": 10,
  "width": 6
},
{
  "_id": "65ef79a3331ab6aef4fae5e5",
  "REF_RoomID": "65ef79a0331ab6aef4fae5be",
  "identifier": "2.1.4x10",
  "active": true,
  "partition": "1",
  "length": 10,
  "width": 4
},
{
  "_id": "65ef79a3331ab6aef4fae5e6",
  "REF_RoomID": "65ef79a0331ab6aef4fae5be",
  "identifier": "2.2.4x10",
  "active": true,
  "partition": "2",
  "length": 10,
  "width": 4
},
{
  "_id": "65ef79a3331ab6aef4fae5e7",
  "REF_RoomID": "65ef79a0331ab6aef4fae5be",
  "identifier": "2.3.4x10",
  "active": true,
  "partition": "3",
  "length": 10,
  "width": 4
}
```

**Bookings**

```
{
  "_id": "65ef88f444e7d6607498ac2e",
  "REF_KennelID": "65ef79a2331ab6aef4fae5d4",
  "year": 2024,
  "dayOfYear": 100,
  "duration": 6
},
{
  "_id": "65f0ca69f2667460e600a46a",
  "REF_KennelID": "65ef79a2331ab6aef4fae5d4",
  "year": 2024,
  "dayOfYear": 107,
  "duration": 1
}
```

thank you !

**ANSWER**

here is the pipeline that works - thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431750/aneroid for pushing me down the right path !

```
let pipeline = [
    {
      $match: {
        active: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "rooms",
        localField: "REF_RoomID",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "room",
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "room.number": {
          $in: ["1","2"],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$room",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "bookings",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "REF_KennelID",
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              year: {
                $in: [2024],
              },
              dayOfYear: {
                $in: [100],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        as: "bookings",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$bookings",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        identifier: {
          $first: "$identifier",
        },
        active: {
          $first: "$active",
        },
        partition: {
          $first: "$partition",
        },
        length: {
          $first: "$length",
        },
        width: {
          $first: "$width",
        },
        bookings: {
          $push: "$bookings",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        "bookings.REF_KennelID": 0,
        "bookings.__v": 0,
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        identifier: 1,
      },
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `$match` stage for kennels being `active` should be first in your pipeline. So the lookups won't be performed for unmatched kennels which improves performance.
2. In the first `$lookup` stage, [use a lookup-`pipeline`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#correlated-subqueries-using-concise-syntax) instead of only field-equality followed by a match for room numbers. This is needed because *"I want to return is all active kennels"*.

   - In the current form, any active kennel which doesn't have room "1" or "2" would not show up in the results at all.
3. Same goes for the second `$lookup` stage - use a pipeline to get all kennels regardless of whether they have matching bookings or not, or even *any bookings*.

```js
db.kennels.aggregate([
  { $match: { active: true } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "rooms",
      let: { searchRoomID: "$REF_RoomID" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$_id", "$$searchRoomID"] },
                { $in: ["$number", ["1", "2"]] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "room"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$room",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "bookings",
      let: { searchKennelID: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$REF_KennelID", "$$searchKennelID"] },
                { $eq: ["$year", 2024] },
                { $in: ["$dayOfYear", [100, 101, 102, 103]] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "bookings"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$bookings",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      identifier: { $first: "$identifier" },
      active: { $first: "$active" },
      partition: { $first: "$partition" },
      length: { $first: "$length" },
      width: { $first: "$width" },
      bookings: { $push: "$bookings" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "bookings.REF_KennelID": 0,
      "bookings.__v": 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JAaYjR46_dg)

Notes:

- You probably need some `$sort` stage at the end or before the `$group`.
- It's unclear why you're doing a lookup with `rooms` at all.

  - You check for room = "1" or "2" but then you remove it from the results, and you're returning all kennels anyway. So a kennel with *only* room "3" would be in the results regardless of that condition.
  - `bookings` refer to `kennels` and not `rooms` so the room lookup adds no value here. Your links to bookings and rooms are independent of each other and only connected via kennels.
- If you actually only want `kennels` which have room "1" or "2", and NOT the full list of kennels, then change the unwind after the room-lookup from `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true` to `false`. So any kennels which don't have those rooms will not be in the results.

Comment: one small change .. then it's perfect : dayOfYear: { $in: [100] }

Comment: whoops... spoke too soon... set number: { $in: ["1"] } and run it.. it returns kennel 2 as well as kennel 1  see this playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/7G39iFrhoUM

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431750/aneroid... an 'a' in the playground for a room returns all rooms https://mongoplayground.net/p/1WWb5f69t5H

Comment: @MrLister _"it returns kennel 2 as well as kennel 1"_ You said you wanted _all kennels_. So If the room doesn't match, the kennel would still be returned. Your links to bookings and rooms are independent of each other and only connected via kennels. You're basically doing two separate lookups. This is all very "relational", so are you sure you want to be using Mongo for this at all?

Comment: @MrLister Updated the answer to fix the two pipelines. Also see updated notes.